# Why do I need a memory barrier?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, shared-memory, memory-barriers

C# 4 in a Nutshell (highly recommended btw) uses the following code to demonstrate the concept of MemoryBarrier (assuming A and B were run on different threads):

```
class Foo{
  int _answer;
  bool complete;
  void A(){
    _answer = 123;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier(); // Barrier 1
    _complete = true;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier(); // Barrier 2
  }
  void B(){
    Thread.MemoryBarrier(); // Barrier 3;
    if(_complete){
      Thread.MemoryBarrier(); // Barrier 4;
      Console.WriteLine(_answer);
    }
  }
}
```

they mention that Barriers 1 & 4 prevent this example from writing 0 and Barriers 2 & 3 provide a *freshness* guarantee: they ensure that if B ran after A, reading **_complete** would evaluate to **true**.

I'm not really getting it.  I think I understand why Barriers 1 & 4 are necessary: we don't want the write to **_answer** to be optimized and placed after the write to **_complete** (Barrier 1) and we need to make sure that **_answer** is not cached (Barrier 4).  I also think I understand why Barrier 3 is necessary: if A ran until just after writing **_complete = true**, B would still need to refresh **_complete** to read the right value.

I don't understand though why we need Barrier 2!  Part of me says that it's because perhaps Thread 2 (running B) already ran until (but not including) **if(_complete)** and so we need to insure that **_complete** is refreshed.

However, I don't see how this helps.  Isn't it still possible that **_complete** will be set to true in A but yet the B method will see a cached (false) version of **_complete**?  Ie, if Thread 2 ran method B until after the first MemoryBarrier and then Thread 1 ran method A until **_complete = true** but no further, and then Thread 1 resumed and tested **if(_complete)** -- could that **if** not result in **false**?

Comment: Why would anyone use this over `volatile`?

Comment: @Chaos: CLR via C# book (Richter) has a great explanation - IIRC it's that 'volatile' means all accesses to the var are treated as volatile and enforce full memory barriers in both directions.  That's often way more perf hit than necessary if you instead only need a read or a write barrier and only in particular accesses.

Comment: @Chaos: not really the point, but one reason is that volatile has its own quirks in regards to compiler optimizations that might lead to deadlock, see http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2009/02/24/TheMagicalDuelingDeadlockingSpinLocks.aspx

Comment: @statichippo: seriously, if you're dealing with this kind of code (more than just learning about it), please get Richter's book, I can't recommend it enough.

http://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-Dev-Pro-Jeffrey-Richter/dp/0735627045

Comment: I'm not on a regular basis, but definitely will get the book!

Comment: @James - Makes sense, mainly I have been experimenting with immutability with some light locking when the need arises. Can you think of a quick example where this would be useful?

Comment: @James: the volatile keyword enforces "half" barriers (load-acquire + store-release) - not full barriers. If you're quoting Richter, then he's wrong on this point. There's a good explanation in Joe Duffy's "Concurrent Programming in Windows".

Comment: @albahari - I'm sure it's me misremembering that chunk of Richter's book - admittedly it's something I haven't had to deal with very much in my own coding.

Comment: I'm begining to wonder if anyone ever wrote a peice of code that required MemoryBarriers that didn't have a bug in.

Comment: Regarding volatile, it's best understood if you think of it as enforcing *no* memory barriers, but instead preventing compiler and CPU optimisations that could cause unexpected behaviour due to the likes of variable hoisting, To think of it otherwise is to play with fire.

Comment: This topic is mentioned hardly anywhere, I found that by pure random. I wonder who plasters his code with barriers like shown, who understands this whole thing enough to prevent every case? Who can read this code effectively? I'd bet most applications are unsecured all over. Wow ... this is frightening.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Barrier #2 guarentees that the write to `_complete` gets committed immediately. Otherwise it could remain in a queued state meaning that the read of `_complete` in `B` would not see the change caused by `A` even though `B` effectively used a volatile read.

Of course, this example does not quite do justice to the problem because `A` does nothing more after writing to `_complete` which means that the write will be comitted immediately anyway since the thread terminates early.

The answer to your question of whether the `if` could still evaluate to `false` is yes for exactly the reasons you stated. But, notice what the author says regarding this point.

> Barriers 1 and 4 prevent this example
>   from writing “0”. Barriers 2 and 3
>   provide a freshness guarantee: they
>   ensure that **if B ran after A**, reading
>   _complete would evaluate to true.

The emphasis on "if B ran after A" is mine. It certainly could be the case that the two threads interleave. But, the author was ignoring this scenario presumably to make his point regarding how `Thread.MemoryBarrier` works simpler.

By the way, I had a hard time contriving an example on my machine where barriers #1 and #2 would have altered the behavior of the program. This is because the memory model regarding writes was strong in my environment. Perhaps, if I had a multiprocessor machine, was using Mono, or had some other different setup I could have demonstrated it. Of course, it was easy to demonstrate that removing barriers #3 and #4 had an impact.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful.  I guess I wasn't as clueless as I thought.

Comment: I don't understand both barrier 2 *and* 3 are needed in the case that B runs after A. Both are full fences, so any one of them would do alone, would it not ?

Comment: @ohadsc: Memory barriers influence the behavior of a single thread only. Consider that A and B may be running on different CPUs. If you removed barrier 2 then the write might not be commited. If you removed barrier 3 then the read might not be refreshed. The barriers in A have no impact on the execution of B and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. If you get the time, please see my question regarding your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574389/thread-safe-usage-of-lock-helpers-concerning-memory-barriers/6575415#6575415

Comment: I don't understand memory barrier#4(is it necessary?). The #3 already makes sure that we "invalidate" memory cache and have up to date values. And _answer is guaranteed to have value first. What am I missing?

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa: Barrier #4 prevents `_answer` from being read before `_complete` which could result in the program printing 0 if A and B are interleaving.

Answer (score 5):

The example is unclear for two reasons:

1. It is too simple to fully show what's happening with the fences.
2. Albahari is including requirements for non-x86 architectures. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.memorybarrier(v=vs.110).aspx): "MemoryBarrier is required only on multiprocessor systems with weak memory ordering (for example, a system employing multiple Intel Itanium processors [which Microsoft no longer supports]).".

If you consider the following, it becomes clearer:

1. A memory barrier (full barriers here - .Net doesn't provide a half barrier) prevents read / write instructions from jumping the fence (due to various optimisations). This guarantees us the code after the fence will execute after the code before the fence.
2. "This serializing operation guarantees that every load and store instruction that precedes in program order the MFENCE instruction is globally visible before any load or store instruction that follows the MFENCE instruction is globally visible." See [here](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_170.html).
3. x86 CPUs have a strong memory model and guarantee writes appear consistent to all threads / cores (therefore barriers #2 & #3 are unneeded on x86). But, we are not guaranteed that reads and writes will remain in coded sequence, hence the need for barriers #1 and #4.
4. Memory barriers are inefficient and needn't be used (see the same MSDN article). I personally use Interlocked and volatile (make sure you know how to use it correctly!!), which work efficiently and are easy to understand.

Ps. [This article](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/11/05/who-ordered-memory-fences-on-an-x86/) explains the inner workings of x86 nicely.