# Thread safe usage of lock helpers (concerning memory barriers)

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, memory-barriers

By lock helpers I am referring to disposable objects with which locking can be implemented via `using` statements. For example, consider a typical usage of the `SyncLock` class from [Jon Skeet's MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/locking.html):

```
public class Example
{
    private readonly SyncLock _padlock;

    public Example()
    {
        _padlock = new SyncLock();
    }

    public void ConcurrentMethod()
    {
        using (_padlock.Lock())
        {
            // Now own the padlock - do concurrent stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Now, consider the following usage:

```
var example = new Example();
new Thread(example.ConcurrentMethod).Start();
```

My question is this - since `example` is created on one thread and `ConcurrentMethod` is called on another, couldn't `ConcurrentMethod`'s thread be oblivious to `_padock`'s assignment in the constructor (due to thread caching / read-write reordering), and thus throw a `NullReferenceException` (on `_padLock` itself) ?

I know that locking with `Monitor`/`lock` has the benefit of memory barriers, but when using lock helpers such as these I can't see why such barriers are guaranteed. In that case, as far as I understand, the constructor would have to be modified:

```
public Example()
{
    _padlock = new SyncLock();
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
}
```

Source: [Understanding the Impact of Low-Lock Techniques in Multithreaded Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163715.aspx)

**EDIT** Hans Passant suggests that the creation of a thread implies a memory barrier. So how about:

```
var example = new Example();
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s => example.ConcurrentMethod());
```

Now a thread is not necessarily created...

Comment: At what point in time do you think it might have a cached `null` floating around?

Comment: In addition to Marc: the `_padLock` ref doesn't change so caching is irrelevant. The first read will happen _after_ it is set. Your question would have more merit if it was create-on-demand or something.

Comment: Starting a thread is in itself enough to force caches to be updated.  You'll have to come up with a better example.

Comment: @Marc, Henk - the ctor's thread can assign the synclock into its cache, not showing up in the main memory, which ConcurrentMethod's thread may then read

Comment: @Hans - I was relying on Joseph Albahari's threading tutorial that states: "The following implicitly generate full fences: C#'s lock statement (Monitor.Enter/Monitor.Exit), All methods on the Interlocked class (we’ll cover these soon), Asynchronous callbacks that use the thread pool — these include asynchronous delegates, APM callbacks, and Task continuations, Setting and waiting on a signaling construct, Anything that relies on signaling, such as starting or waiting on a Task"... So starting a thread would get into the "signaling" category?

Comment: so really, you're asking "at what point is it guaranteed to have flushed ctor initialisation into main memory" ?

Comment: It is a side effect of operating system code.  That doesn't conveniently fit a C# pigeonhole.

Comment: @Marc well I didn't think a ctor had different rules than any other method call in this regard

Comment: @Hans - As if concurrent programming weren't hard enough :) How about a threadpool thread, then? see my edit

Comment: It is no different.  Waking up a tp thread still involves an internal synchronization that syncs the caches.  So does any thread context switch.

Comment: @Hans I see, thanks. If you'd like, I'll gladly accept your answer if you posted one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you do not need to do anything special to guarentee that memory barriers are created. This is because almost any mechanism used to get a method executing on another thread produces a *release-fence* barrier on the calling thread and an *aquire-fence* barrier on the worker thread (actually they may be full fence barriers). So either `QueueUserWorkItem` or `Thread.Start` will automatically insert the necessary barriers. Your code is safe.

Also, as a matter of tangential interest `Thread.Sleep` also generates a memory barrier. This is interesting because some people naively use `Thread.Sleep` to simulate thread interleaving. If this strategy were used to troubleshoot low-lock code then it could very well mask the problem you were trying to find.

Comment: +1 for 'Thread.Sleep also generates a memory barrier' - extremely interesting notion, if it is indeed true

Comment: Very interesting indeed. So in most cases, I wouldn't need memory barriers in the ctor, since the thread that created the object would usually be the one working on it (or dispatching other threads to work on it, which will incur a memory barrier). Is that about right ?