# explanation to Thread.Yield assumption

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, race-condition

Can someone explain me this:

> if inserting **Thread.Yield()** anywhere in your code makes or breaks the program, you almost certainly have a bug.

I've read it here : http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: Please don't start your titles with things like "C#" - that's what tags are for. Even more so, this question has nothing to do with C# - it's a pure .NET question.

Comment: That's wishful thinking.  Could work, but just not very likely.  Flushing out threading race bugs requires a bigger weapon.  A good gun is Microsoft Lab's CHESS tool, it injects random delays into threads.  http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/

Comment: @Hans: afair, chess does not only injects random delays, it is capable of analyzing control flow of the program and model different execution scenarios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can only guess to the author's intent, but: thread scheduling is already indeterminate. If adding the yield makes it work, then I infer that the reality here is that it is relying on the side-effect of a race condition, i.e. giving some CPU to another thread allows the timings to coincide such that the right thing happens. Well, you don't know ***what*** you are yielding to on a parallel system, and on a milticore system you may well not be yielding to the same thing (yield is same CPU only). As such, the only *sane* way to do this is with a structure such as a Monitor, Mutex, Semaphore, ResetEvent, or some other locking primitive designed for allowing controlled flow between threads and (sometimes) processes.

Answer (score 2):

My assumption, which I have discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581848/memory-barrier-generators/6932271#6932271), is that `Thread.Yield` generates an implicit memory barrier. If you had a memory barrier issue it could disappear by adding a call to `Thread.Yield`. This is similar to how using `Thread.Sleep` to simulate thread interleaving can actually wind up masking a problem. Also, `Thread.Yield` will obviously change the timing of when instructions get executed and that can have an impact on whether or not a race condition is observed or not.