# C# While Loop in Worker Thread for listening command and response

Tags: c#, multithreading

**Overview of the problem:**

I try to use a thread (while..loop) to listen a command from user.  If user send a command, it will assign new value in the global variable which is in the class (LoopingWorkerThread).

I don't understand if I don't put the thread sleep value lower than 10 milliseconds, and I wouldn't get any response (it is in the ListenCommand method) .  Look like the global parameter is being overwritten "_CommandReceived" in the method, probably the processor run to fast and ignore the value of the parameter had changed ("_CommandReceived").

Kindly comment if there is any better mechanism.  I had lock it in the ListenCommand while loop.

**The following are the codes:**

```
public class LoopingWorkerThread
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Local main thread for LoopingWorkerThread
        /// </summary>
        private Thread t;
        /// <summary>
        /// Local parameter to identify the LoopingWorkerThread Is On
        /// </summary>
        private bool _IsOn;
        /// <summary>
        /// Local parameter to store command received from user
        /// </summary>
        private int _CommandReceived;
        /// <summary>
        /// Local object to use for locking the LoopingWorker Thread
        /// </summary>
        private object _LockListenCommand = new object();
        /// <summary>
        /// Properties of LoopingWorker Thread Is On
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsOn
        {
            get { return _IsOn; }
            set { _IsOn = value; }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Property of storing the command received from user
        /// </summary>
        public int CommandReceived
        {
            get { return _CommandReceived; }
            set { _CommandReceived = value; }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Delegate for OnResponse Event Handler
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        public delegate void OnResponseHandler(object sender, ResponseArg e);
        /// <summary>
        /// Event of OnResponse
        /// </summary>
        public event OnResponseHandler OnResponse;
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor of LoopingWorkerThread Class
        /// </summary>
        public LoopingWorkerThread()
        {
            _IsOn = false;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Method of LoopingWorkerThread Function
        /// </summary>
        private void ListenCommand()
        {
            lock (_LockListenCommand)
                while (_IsOn)
                {
                    switch (_CommandReceived)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            // Ignore default command
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            FireOnResponse("Received cmd 1, response [Hello One]");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            FireOnResponse("Received cmd 2, response [Hello Two]");
                            break;
                        default:
                            FireOnResponse("Error. Received unidentified command - " + _CommandReceived.ToString());
                            break;
                    }

                    //Console.WriteLine("ThreadProc: Cmd:[{0}] - Response:{1}", _CommandReceived.ToString(), ReaderResponse);

                    // Reset or Clear the Command Received
                    _CommandReceived = 0;

                    // If the sleep less than 10 millisecond, it always don't catch the 
                    // command received which assigned to 1 or 2. Don't understand, or is there
                    // any better method.
                    **Thread.Sleep(10);**
                }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Function of firing response event back to user
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        private void FireOnResponse(string message)
        {
            ResponseArg myarg = new ResponseArg(message);
            if (OnResponse != null)
                OnResponse(this, myarg);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Method of starting the LoopingWorkerThread
        /// </summary>
        public void Start()
        {
            _IsOn = true;

            FireOnResponse("Main thread: Started.");

            // The constructor for the Thread class requires a ThreadStart 
            // delegate that represents the method to be executed on the 
            // thread.  C# simplifies the creation of this delegate.
            t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenCommand));

            // Start ThreadProc.  Note that on a uniprocessor, the new 
            // thread does not get any processor time until the main thread 
            // is preempted or yields.  Uncomment the Thread.Sleep that 
            // follows t.Start() to see the difference.
            t.Start();

            //Thread.Sleep(0);

            FireOnResponse("Main thread: Call Start().");

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Method of stopping the LoopingWorkerThread
        /// </summary>
        public void Stop()
        {
            _IsOn = false;
            t.Join();
            //t.Abort();

            FireOnResponse("LoopingWorker Thread is stopped.");
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Method of sending command to the LoopingWorkerThread
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="readercmd"></param>
        public void SendCommand(int readercmd)
        {
            _CommandReceived = readercmd;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you locking `_LockLisenCommand`, when there'll never be more than 1 active thread?

Comment: Do you mean that my class only is running one thread, which is not necessary to lock it, right? Yes, I think it is not necessary.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I am using .Net framework 3.5

Answer (score 4):

Your code works because [`Thread.Sleep` produces the necessary memory barrier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6932271/158779) required to read `_commandReceived` correctly. If you remove the `Thread.Sleep` call then you also remove the implicit memory barrier. Obviously, this is not a good mechanism to rely on though.

More importantly you are going about this the wrong way. What you should be using is the producer-consumer pattern. This is pretty easy with the `BlockingCollection` class since it blocks the consumer on `Take` while the queue is empty.

```
public class Example
{
  private BlockingCollection<int> commands = new BlockingCollection<int>();

  public Example()
  {
    var thread = new Thread(Run);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
  }

  public void SendCommmand(int command)
  {
    commands.Add(command);
  }

  private void Run()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      int command = commands.Take();
      ProcessCommand(command);      
    }
  }

  private void ProcessCommand(int command)
  {
    // Process the command here.
  }
}
```

`BlockingCollection` is available for 3.5 as part of the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) download.

Comment: Just a thought: You could make up a `Stop` method, which adds `null` to `commands`, and then have a condition check in the `Run` method. If the `command` is equal to `null`, then break out of the while loop.

Comment: @ebb: Yup, you'd have to use `int?` instead of `int`, but yeah, that is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the variable volatile. More about this on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx

Comment: Great Prafulla. It worked.  I placed the thread sleep value even 0 milliseconds, it responded correctly.  If I commented the thread sleep, it will not responded.  Anyway, this is great for me.

Comment: Hi Prafulla, I tried in my Windows form, if I put a loop to fires the SendCommand method 10 times, when I click my send button; I only get the one response, my expect result which is 10 response. However, if I manual click 10 times, I get the 10 responses.  Do you know why?