# Severe bugs in SimplePriorityQueue example on MSDN

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, priority-queue

I need to use a concurrent priority queue, and I was considering adapting the `SimplePriorityQueue<TPriority, TValue>` sample given in the [How to: Add Bounding and Blocking Functionality to a Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460690%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tutorial on MSDN. However, I was surprised at the severity of the bugs that the said sample seems to have. Could someone verify whether these issues are really present?

**1)** A race hazard exists between `TryAdd` and `ToArray`, which can cause an `ArgumentException` to be thrown from the latter. The `TryAdd` method first adds an item to an internal queue, then increments the `m_count` counter. On the other hand, `ToArray` first initializes a new array of size `m_count`, then copies the internal queues onto this array. If `TryAdd` is called whilst `ToArray` is being executed, then `ToArray` might end up attempting to copy more items than it had allocated space for in the array, causing the [`CopyTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287188(v=vs.110).aspx) call to throw an `ArgumentException`.

```
private ConcurrentQueue<KeyValuePair<int, TValue>>[] _queues;
private int m_count;

// ...

// IProducerConsumerCollection members
public bool TryAdd(KeyValuePair<int, TValue> item)
{
    _queues[item.Key].Enqueue(item);
    Interlocked.Increment(ref m_count);
    return true;
}    

public int Count
{
    get { return m_count; }
}

public KeyValuePair<int, TValue>[] ToArray()
{
    KeyValuePair<int, TValue>[] result;

    lock (_queues)
    {
        result = new KeyValuePair<int, TValue>[this.Count];
        // *** context switch here; new item gets added ***
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var q in _queues)
        {
            if (q.Count > 0)
            {
                q.CopyTo(result, index);   // *** ArgumentException ***
                index += q.Count;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**2)** Another race hazard exists in the `GetEnumerator` method: There is no synchronization between updates to the internal queues.

```
public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<int, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < priorityCount; i++)
    {
        foreach (var item in _queues[i])
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

Consider the following code snippet, which takes an item from the queue and re-adds it with incremented priority:

```
if (queue.TryTake(out item) && item.Key < maxPriority - 1)
    queue.TryAdd(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(item.Key + 1, item.Value))
```

If the above snippet were run concurrently with an enumeration, one would expect the item to appear at most once, either with the original or with the incremented priority – or, possibly, not appear at all. One would not expect the item to appear *twice*, at both priorities. However, since the `GetEnumerator` iterates over its internal queues sequentially, it does not protect against such ordering inconsistencies across queues.

**3)** The public `Count` property can return stale values, since it reads the shared `m_count` field without any memory fences. If a consumer accesses this property in a loop that doesn't generate memory fences of its own, such as the below, they could be stuck in an infinite loop, despite items being added to the queue by other threads.

```
while (queue.Count == 0) 
{ }
```

The need for memory fences when reading shared variables has been discussed in several other posts:

- [How to correctly read an Interlocked.Increment'ed int field?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6139699/1149773)
- [Reading an int that's updated by Interlocked on other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24808291/1149773)
- [Do concurrent interlocked and reads require a memory barrier or locking?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9834556/1149773)

**4)** There is no memory barrier between the initialization of the `_queues` array and the completion of the `SimplePriorityQueue` constructor. Race hazards could arise when external consumers on another thread call `TryAdd` and access `_queues` *before* its initialization has completed (or appears as completed on their memory cache). This is discussed further in my other question on [constructors and memory barriers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38881722/1149773).

**5)** `TryTake` and `ToArray` are protected through the use of the `lock` keyword. Apart from being inadequate (due to the bugs discussed above), this also defeats the entire purpose of designing a concurrent collection. Given its shortcomings, I think the best approach would be to downgrade the internal `ConcurrentQueue` structures to plain `Queue`, add locks everywhere, and start treating this as a non-concurrent but thread-safe structure.

Comment: Yea, examples on the MSDN are not always the greatest.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: True; even fundamental topics on parallelism, such as for the [`volatile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx) keyword, have blatant flaws. But I've never seen such a mess on MSDN as the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on how you are going use the class. If you limit yourself to `TryAdd` and `TryTake` (which is the two main things `BlockingCollection<T>` relies on) you shouldn't have any issues and you will have a very fast lock minimal priority queue.

If you start using `Count`, `CopyTo`, or any of the other methods you are potentially going to run in to the issues you pointed out.

Comment: I figured most issues wouldn't manifest if wrapped in a `BlockingCollection<T>`, although I still think that's a huge implementation-dependent assumption to make.