# Are there any implicit memory barriers in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, memory-model

In the following code, is using atomics necessary to guarantee race-free semantics on all platforms or does the use the use of a promise.set_value/future.wait imply some kind of implicit memory barrier that would allow me to rely on the flag write having become visible to the outer thread?

```
std::atomic_bool flag{false}; // <- does this need to be atomic?
runInThreadPoolBlocking([&]() {
    // do something
    flag.store(true);
});
if (flag.load()) // do something


// simplified runInThreadPoolBlocking implementation
template <typename Callable>
void runInThreadPoolBlocking(Callable func)
{
    std::promise<void> prom;
    auto fut = prom.get_future();

    enqueueToThreadPool([&]() {
        func();
        prom.set_value();
    });

    fut.get();
}
```

In general, are there any "implicit" memory barriers guaranteed by the standard for things like thread.join() or futures?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55932983/will-calling-thread-see-modifications-to-local-variables-after-thread-join#55932983) for an answer with regard to thread.join() (The answer is yes for thread.join())

Comment: I asked a [similar question about constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459833/does-the-c-memory-model-provide-guarantees-about-the-operations-of-constructor).

Comment: As is also already answered; the join() causes a "normal" sequenced-before relationship - the same as you have within a single thread when one instruction is put before another; so in that sense you can see this a "the same" thread and therefore an atomic is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`thread.join()` and `promise.set_value()`/`future.wait()` guarantee to imply memory barriers.

Using `atomic_bool` is necessary if you don't want the compiler to reorder boolean check or assignment with other code. But in that particular case you can use not atomic `bool`. That `flag` will be guaranteed to be `true` in the moment of check if you don't use it in any other place, as the assignment and check are on the opposite sides of synchronisation point (`fut.get()`) (forcing the compiler to load real `flag` value) and the function `runInThreadPoolBlocking()` is guaranteed to finish only after the lambda is executed.

Quoting from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/future/get/) for `future::get()`, for example:

> **Data races**
>
> ---
>
> The future object is modified. The shared state is accessed as an
>   atomic operation (causing no data races).

The same is for `promise::set_value()`. Besides other stuff

> ... atomic operation (causing no data races) ...

means no one of the conflicting evaluations happens before another (strict memory ordering).

So do all of `std::` multithreading synchronization primitives and tools, where you expect some operations to occur only before or after the synchronization point (like `std::mutex::lock()` or `unlock()`, `thread::join()`, etc.).

Note that any operations on the thread object itself are not synchronized with `thread::join()` (unlike the operations within the thread it represents).

Answer (score -2):

```
std::atomic_bool flag{false}; // <- does this need to be atomic?
```

**Yes**.

The call:

```
prom.get_future()
```

returns a `std::future<void>` object.

For the future, the reference says the following:

> The class template std::future provides a mechanism to access the
>   result of asynchronous operations:
>
> An asynchronous operation (created via std::async, std::packaged_task, or std::promise) can provide a std::future object
>   to the creator of that asynchronous operation.
>
> The creator of the asynchronous operation can then use a variety of methods to query, wait for, or extract a value from the
>   std::future. **These methods may block if the asynchronous operation has
>   not yet provided a value.**
>
> When the asynchronous operation is ready to send a result to the creator, it can do so by modifying shared state (e.g.
>   std::promise::set_value) that is linked to the creator's std::future.
>
> Note that std::future references shared state that is not shared with any other asynchronous return objects (as opposed to
>   std::shared_future).

You don't store a 'return' value here so the point is kind of mute, and since there is no other guarentees (and the whole idea is that threads may run in parallel anyway ! ) you need to keep the bool atomic if it's shared !

Comment: What do you mean by shared? I think the author of the question asks if the "other" code in his example will be enough to put just `bool` instead of atomic in that particular case.