# Will a calling thread see modifications to local variables after thread.join()?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, thread-safety, memory-model

In the simplest possible example, let's say I have a function that starts a thread, which in turn sets the value of a local variable to true. We join the thread, then leave the function.

```
bool func() {
    bool b = false;
    std::thread t([&]() { b = true; }); 
    t.join();
    return b;
}
```

Will this function return true, or is the behavior undefined?

Comment: It doesn't matter that a variable is local or global, as long as its lifetime is sufficient (as here).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it must return true.

> **[thread.thread.member]**
>
> ```
> void join();
> ```
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/thread.thread.class#thread.thread.member-4) *Effects*:  Blocks until the thread represented by `*this` has completed.
>
> [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/thread.thread.class#thread.thread.member-5) *Synchronization*: The completion of the thread represented by `*this` synchronizes with ([intro.multithread]) the corresponding successful `join()` return.

So the execution of the thread represented by the handle, and associated side effects are done before `join` returns to the calling context.

#### Example

Let's look at two functions, which differ only in when they join a thread:

```
int count_A() {
    int counter = 0;
    bool flag(true);
    auto t = std::thread([&]{flag = false;});

    while(flag) {    // infinite loop - flag never synchronized
        ++counter;
    }
    t.join();        // joins thread after loop exits
    return counter;
}
int count_B() {
    int counter = 0;
    bool flag(true);
    auto t = std::thread([&]{flag = false;});

    t.join();       // joins thread before loop, forcing synchronization
    while(flag) {
        ++counter;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

When compiled with g++ version 8.2 at `-O3` optimization, invoking `count_A` results in an infinite loop because the compiler assumes `flag` is always true.

On the other hand, invoking `count_B` will just return a value of `0`. Because the value of `flag` is checked after `thread.join()`, it's value is re-loaded, and flag is `false` so the while loop doesn't execute.

Note that if `flag` is changed to an `atomic_bool`, then `count_A` has the intended behavior of incrementing the counter until the flag is set to false, and the function *does not* enter an infinite loop (instead returning once `flag` is set to false by the child thread).

Comment: @J.Antonio - Did you intend to self-answer this post?

Comment: No, but after you answered it I played around with some code to get a better sense of things, and I figured it'd be a good addition to the answer. I really appreciate you taking the time to look up the corresponding portion of the standard that addresses this

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez - NP. I just thought I possibly cut in line while you were posting an answer. For posterity, it's worth mentioning that one can self-answer before even posting a question, there's a checkbox that opens the answer panel above "ask".

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I honestly didn't know what the standard said with regard to this, and I didn't feel like I was in a position to provide a comprehensive answer