# Do I need memory barrier for accessing memory modified by the thread that finished?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, barrier

[*Hereinafter, C++ terms*]


I have a thread A and thread B that share access to the integer value P. Thread A initializes this value and updates it while running. Then thread A completes. Thread B waits for thread A to complete (standard OS API call, whatever OS is used) and wants to read P. 


Does thread B need a memory barrier to read a coherent, last set by thread A, value of P? Is there a possibility that when OS API says "thread A finished", the changes of memory it modified are not visible to other threads yet?


Note that there **only one** thread writing the value here, which may or may not distinguish this question from "[Is there an implicit memory barrier with synchronized-with relationship on thread::join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42175207/is-there-an-implicit-memory-barrier-with-synchronized-with-relationship-on-threa)" asked before. My gut feeling tells me the answer should be the same, but...

Comment: This sounds like a job for `std::future.

Comment: From reading [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.thread.member#4) , I'd say that yes - .join() does synchronize, and you don't need a memory barrier. But that text is not written for normal mortals to interpret, so I'll leave the answering to someone else. Maybe also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444891/are-memory-barriers-required-when-joining-on-a-thread?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join` synchronizes with the thread that calls `join`. That is, all writes that `A` makes will become visible to `B` when `B` calls `A.join()`.

You can think of this as `A` executing `std::atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release)` as it finishes and `B` executing `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire` as `A` joins.

> Does thread B need a memory barrier

Yes, but they are implicit in `join` and you do not have to write them.

> Is there a possibility that when OS API says "thread A finished", the changes of memory it modified are not visible to other threads yet?

Threads other than the caller of `join` will need additional synchronization, e.g. `std::condition_variable` or `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);`