# Lockfree Read value after Interlocked.Exchange?

Tags: c#, multithreading, lock-free, interlocked

Lets say we have a class like so:

```
public class Foo
{
     private Bar bar = new Bar();

    public void DoStuffInThread1()
    {
        var old = Interlocked.Exchange(ref bar,new Bar());
        //do things with old
        //everything is fine here, I'm sure I have the previous bar value
    }

    public void OtherStuffFromThread2()
    {
        //how do I ensure that I have the latest bar ref here
        //considering mem cahces etc
        bar.Something();
    }
}
```

And lets say we have two threads, one operating on `DoStuffInThread1` and another on `OtherStuffFromThread2`.

How do I ensure that thread2 always sees the latest `bar`?
volatile doesn't help. and I don't want old school locks.
There has to be a way to read the correct value of bar with mem barriers/interlocked somehow?

Comment: Hi Roger! :-) I'm curious as to why volatile doesn't help? I'm probably missing someting here...

Comment: How will thread 2 know that there's even supposed to be a 'latest' Bar in `bar`?

Comment: @DanByström I dont know the mechanics behind it, but it doesn't work, thread2 still operate on the same object as thread1 even after the exchange

Comment: Now that's odd. I would have thought it should... :-/

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the point...

Unless you do:

```
public void OtherStuffFromThread2()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //how do I ensure that I have the latest bar ref here
        //considering mem cahces etc
        bar.Something();
    }
}
```

That is something quite improbable, nearly every method you could use on `OtherStuffFromThread2()` to wait for thread1 to be ready will cause an implicit memorybarrier... See for example [Memory barrier generators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6581848/613130) some constructs that cause memorybarriers...

So:

```
public void OtherStuffFromThread2()
{
    Thread.Sleep(Timespan.FromMinutes(1));
    // Implicit MemoryBarrier here :-)

    //how do I ensure that I have the latest bar ref here
    //considering mem cahces etc
    bar.Something();
}
```

If you really want to read the value of a variable, you can read a volatile variable and then read your variable (or read the same volatile variable twice). Why? because a volatile read causes an acquire semantics, which means it can’t be reordered with subsequent memory operations, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645755(v=vs.71).aspx :

> A read of a volatile field is called a volatile read. A volatile read has "acquire semantics"; that is, it is guaranteed to occur prior to any references to memory that occur after it in the instruction sequence.

So if you do:

```
private static int myuselessvolatilefieldthatcanbestatic;
private int thefieldiwanttoread;
```

and then

```
var useless = myuselessvolatilefieldthatcanbestatic;
var iwanttoknow = thefieldiwanttoread;
```

The `thefieldiwanttoread` will contain a value that will be read *after* a new read to `myuselessvolatilefieldthatcanbestatic` has been done.

Note that without a synchronization primitive, it will be difficult to know when the `myuselessvolatilefieldthatcanbestatic` will be done :-), but:

```
while (true)
{
    var useless = myuselessvolatilefieldthatcanbestatic;
    var iwanttoknow = thefieldiwanttoread;
    // Some code goes here
}
```

Now at least you can use your `while (true)` :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the latest available value, you should use something like `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref bar, null, null)`. Checking for null is just for satisfying CompareExchange signature (if `bar` is `null`, then it will set it to `null`). This will give you the latest value that was available among CPUs at the execution moment.