# Why declare a variable as volatile and use Interlocked on it at the same time?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, volatile, interlocked

I am reading Joe Duffy's [Concurrent Programming on Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X). At the end of the chapter "Memory Models and Lock Freedom", he gives an example of the lock free stack. I have gone through the code and there's one thing I don't understand, that is the need for `m_next` field to be marked as `volatile`. Because there is a full memory barrier with `Interlocked.CompareExchange` right? Does anyone have an idea?

I have pasted the sample code below.

```
class LockFreeStack<T>
{
    class Node
    {
        internal T m_value;
        internal volatile Node m_next;
    }

    volatile Node m_head;

    void Push(T value)
    {
        Node n = new Node();
        n.m_value = value;

        Node h;
        do
        {
            h = m_head;
            n.m_next = h;
        }
        while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_head, n, h) != h);
    }

    T Pop()
    {
        Node n;
        do
        {
            n = m_head;
            if (n == null) throw new Exception('stack empty');

        }
        while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_head, n.m_next, n) != n);

        return n.m_value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interlocked and volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186515/interlocked-and-volatile) and [Volatile vs. Interlocked vs. lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154551/volatile-vs-interlocked-vs-lock) and [.NET Volatile.Read/Write and Interlocked scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36501896/net-volatile-read-write-and-interlocked-scope)

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_The_volatile_keyword

Comment: I'm not really advanced in modern and .NET multithreading, but maybe using [Interlocked](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked) on multiple variables even declared volatiles should ensure that, as said in the documentation, the operation is atomic: "*Provides atomic operations for variables that are shared by multiple threads*". That means you won't get aberrant result if another thread modifies any of the vars while doing this operation using Interlocked. Like if you locked all by hand and do this operation yourself with several statements.

Comment: The `m_head` field is also marked as `volatile`. Would you like an explanation for this too, or this is something that you understand?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias He has mentioned "The m_head variable is marked volatile to ensure we properly reread it during the next iteration of the loop."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give my two cents, without being 100% sure that what I am about to say is correct. [Joe Duffy](http://joeduffyblog.com/) is a world-class expert in multithreading, but I think that in this implementation he has been overly cautious regarding the cross-thread visibility of the internal state of the `LockFreeStack<T>` class. The volatility of the `Node.m_next` field is redundant in my opinion. The `Node` instances are mutable, but they are only mutated *before* they are linked in the internal linked list. After that phase they are practically immutable. That mutable phase is performed by a single thread, so there is no chance that another thread may see a stale version of a `Node` instance.

That leaves only the possibility of instructions re-ordering, as a reason for declaring the `Node.m_next` as `volatile`. Since the `n.m_next = h;` assignement is sandwiched between reading another volatile field (`m_head`), and an `Interlocked.CompareExchange` operation, I would *assume* that a possible re-ordering of the instructions that would compromise the correctness of the implementation is already prevented, but as I said I am not 100% sure.

I am pretty sure though that the implementation of the `LockFreeStack<T>` class could be improved performance-wise, at the cost of becoming slightly more allocatey, by making immutable the `Node` class. Nowadays (C# 9) this can be achieved simply by switching from type `class` to type [`record`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records). This is how such an implementation would look like:

```
class LockFreeStack<T>
{
    record Node(T Value, Node Next) { }

    Node _head;

    void Push(T value)
    {
        Node h = Volatile.Read(ref _head);
        while (true)
        {
            Node n = new Node(value, h);
            var original = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _head, n, h);
            if (original == h) break;
            h = original;
        }
    }

    T Pop()
    {
        Node h = Volatile.Read(ref _head);
        while (true)
        {
            if (h == null) throw new Exception("Stack empty");
            var original = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _head, h.Next, h);
            if (original == h) break;
            h = original;
        }
        return h.Value;
    }
}
```

Notice that the cost of volatility is incurred only once for each `Push` or `Pop` operation. One could even argue that the [`Volatile.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile.read) of the `_head` field could be omitted altogether, since a possible stale `_head` value would be corrected anyway by the first [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange) operation, costing only an extra iteration of the `while (true)` loop.