# C# Could write instructions be reordered from finally block into try block?

Tags: c#, volatile, memory-barriers

In an article about [A scalable reader/writer scheme with optimistic retry](http://joeduffyblog.com/2009/06/04/a-scalable-readerwriter-scheme-with-optimistic-retry/) there is a code example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class OptimisticSynchronizer
{
    private volatile int m_version1;
    private volatile int m_version2;

    public void BeforeWrite() {
        ++m_version1;
    }

    public void AfterWrite() {
        ++m_version2;
    }

    public ReadMark GetReadMark() {
        return new ReadMark(this, m_version2);
    }

    public struct ReadMark
    {
        private OptimisticSynchronizer m_sync;
        private int m_version;

        internal ReadMark(OptimisticSynchronizer sync, int version) {
            m_sync = sync;
            m_version = version;
        }

        public bool IsValid {
            get { return m_sync.m_version1 == m_version; }
        }
    }

    public void DoWrite(Action writer) {
        BeforeWrite();
        try {
            writer(); // this is inlined, method call just for example
        } finally {
            AfterWrite();
        }
    }

    public T DoRead<T>(Func<T> reader) {
        T value = default(T);

        SpinWait sw = new SpinWait();
        while (true) {
            ReadMark mark = GetReadMark();

            value = reader();

            if (mark.IsValid) {
                break;
            }

            sw.SpinOnce();
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

If I make `m_version1` and `m_version2` **not volatile** but then use the code:

```
public void DoWrite(Action writer) {
    Thread.MemoryBarrier(); // always there, acquiring write lock with Interlocked method
    Volatile.Write(ref m_version1, m_version1 + 1); // NB we are inside a writer lock, atomic increment is not needed
    try {
        writer();
    } finally {
        // is a barrier needed here to avoid the increment reordered with writer instructions?
        // Volatile.Write(ref m_version2, m_version2 + 1); // is this needed instead of the next line?
        m_version2 = m_version2 + 1; // NB we are inside a writer lock, atomic increment is not needed
        Thread.MemoryBarrier(); // always there, releasing write lock with Interlocked method
    }
}
```

Could instructions from line `m_version2 = m_version2 + 1` be reordered from `finally` into `try` block? It is important that a writer finishes before `m_version2` is incremented.

Logically `finally` is executed after `try`, but the `finally` block is not mentioned in the [list of implicit memory barriers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581848/memory-barrier-generators). *It would be quite confusing* if instructions from `finally` could be moved before the ones from `try`, but CPU optimizations at instructions level are still a black magic for me.

I could put `Thread.MemoryBarrier();` before the line `m_version2 = m_version2 + 1` (or use `Volatile.Write`), but the question is if this is really needed?

The `MemoryBarrier`s shown in the example are implicit and generated by `Interlocked` methods of a writer lock, so they are always there. The danger is that a reader could see `m_version2` incremented before the writer finishes.

Comment: I have read http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf after posting this. It looks like Volatile.Write is needed, there is no special treatment of `finally` (section I.12.6-7). Unless I missed something very subtle about CERs.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find anything in specification that will restrict it, so I checked it with an ARM CPU device (**using Xamarin**, have to check it on Core CLR)... 
One thread was executing this code:

```
try
{
    person = new Person();
}
finally
{
    isFinallyExecuted = true;
}
```

And the second thread was waiting for `isFinallyExecuted` to be `true` with this code:

```
while (!Volatile.Read(ref isFinallyExecuted))
    ;
```

Then the second thread was executing the following code:

```
if (!person.IsInitialized())
{
    failCount++;
    Log.Error("m08pvv", $"Reordered from finally: {failCount}, ok: {okCount}");
}
else
{
    okCount++;
}
```

`IsInitialized` method checks that all fields are properly setted, so it returns `false` for partially constructed objects.

This is what I got in the log:

> 12-25 17:00:55.294: E/m08pvv(11592): Reordered from finally: 48, ok:
>   682245
>  12-25 17:00:56.750: E/m08pvv(11592): Reordered from
>   finally: 49, ok: 686534
>  12-25 17:00:56.830: E/m08pvv(11592):
>   Reordered from finally: 50, ok: 686821
>  12-25 17:00:57.310:
>   E/m08pvv(11592): Reordered from finally: 51, ok: 688002
>  12-25
>   17:01:12.191: E/m08pvv(11592): Reordered from finally: 52, ok:
>   733724
>  12-25 17:01:12.708: E/m08pvv(11592): Reordered from
>   finally: 53, ok: 735338
>  12-25 17:01:13.722: E/m08pvv(11592):
>   Reordered from finally: 54, ok: 738839
>  12-25 17:01:25.240:
>   E/m08pvv(11592): Reordered from finally: 55, ok: 775645

Which means that for 775645 successful runs of that code, 55 times I got `isFinallyExecuted` equals `true` **and** partially constructed object. This is possible because I don't use `Volatile.Write` to store `new Person()` or `volatile` keyword on a `person`.

So, if you have some data races, you will face them.