# Do async and await produce acquire and release semantics?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, language-lawyer, memory-model

I couldn't find a clear answer about whether returning from an `async` method always produces release semantics and whether `await` always produces acquire semantics. I assume yes, because otherwise any `async/await` code would be a minefield?

So here's an example: are returned values both guaranteed to be `100*2` and `12345*2`, without any explicit locks or barriers?

```
private static async Task<(int, int)> AMethod()
{
    // Runs on the original thread:
    var x = 100;
    var y = 12345;

    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Can run on another thread:
        x *= 2;
        y *= 2;

        // Implicit return here, marking the task completed.
        // Release semantics or not?
    });

    await task; // Acquire semantics or not?

    // Runs on the original thread:
    return (x, y);
}
```

EDIT: Of course, `Task.Run` also needs to produce a release and an acquire is needed when starting to run the task's code. Forgot about those in the original question.

Comment: Add `await task.ConfigureAwait(false)` . And then you definitely cannot guarantee that x and y will be  `100*2` and `12345*2`

Comment: @YauhenSampir no, that makes no difference at all to the question.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6932271/1086121

Comment: @YauhenSampir If both the release and acquire are there, you'll still get a good result regardless of `.ConfigureAwait(false)`. If not, it's already broken as is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the returned values are both guaranteed to be `100*2` and `12345*2`, without any explicit locks or barriers.

It's the `Task.Run`, not the `await`, which produces the memory barrier in this case.

To quote the [wonderful Albahari Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx):

> The following implicitly generate full fences:
>
> - C#'s lock statement (Monitor.Enter/Monitor.Exit)
> - All methods on the Interlocked class (we’ll cover these soon)
> - **Asynchronous callbacks that use the thread pool — these include asynchronous delegates, APM callbacks, and Task continuations**
> - Setting and waiting on a signaling construct
> - **Anything that relies on signaling, such as starting or waiting on a Task**
>
> By virtue of that last point, the following is thread-safe:
>
> ```
> int x = 0;
> Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => x++);
> t.Wait();
> Console.WriteLine (x);    // 1
> ```

`Task.Run` wraps `ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem`, which falls under "Asynchronous callbacks that use the thread pool".

See [Memory barrier generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581848/memory-barrier-generators) for a more comprensive list of things that create memory barriers.

Comment: Of course, acquire and release are required for starting the task as well, not just finishing. Duh. Thanks for mentioning that. Will edit the question.