# Is volatile is needed for basic primitive read write operations?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, volatile

I've read many articles that compare volatiles and locks. From my understanding `lock` guarantees that only one thread can use the lock and run the critical code in parallel, and `volatile` disables the memory optimization - so they are not replaceable. Using `volatile` should not replace a `lock`. Although most of the articles are not using `lock` when they show examples of `volatile`.

Say I have such a super simple class:

```
class Foo 
{
    private bool bar;
    private static readonly object barLock = new object();

    public void ToggleBar()
    {
        lock (barLock)
        {
            bar = !bar;
        }
    }

    public bool ReadBar()
    {
        lock (barLock)
        {
            return bar;
        }
    }
}
```

Say the `ToggleBar` is used by thread A and `ReadBar` by thread B, only.

The `lock` protects from the two threads to access the variable in parallel. But should `bar` be `volatile` as well?

In most of the articles I've read, this was the "recommended" solution (also Interlocked class), but for my understanding it, it doesn't solve the issue that `volatile` solves - even with the lock thread B may read an old value of `bar` due to memory optimizations and caching, isn't it?

Shouldn't `bar` be a `volatile` **in addition** to the `lock` in this case?

Comment: No. The lock creates a memory barrier

Comment: Ahh, I see. That is what I missed. Thank you

Comment: You might find this interesting: [Memory barrier generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581848/memory-barrier-generators)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runtime is allowed to move memory access for optimization. If there is a lock, the memory access may not be moved before entering or after leaving the lock. See also this [blog post by Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/12/can-i-skip-the-lock-when-reading-an-integer/):

> The C# compiler, JIT compiler and CPU are all permitted to make
> optimizations provided that the optimization is undetectable by the
> current thread. In particular, reads and writes of variables may be
> re-ordered or eliminated entirely provided that doing so is not
> observable to the current thread. [...] A lock introduces a restriction on these optimizations. In particular: no read may be moved before the beginning of a lock statement, and no write may be moved after the end of a lock statement.

Hence for example in your `ToggleBar` method, you can be sure that the bar variable is read after the method is entered and it has been written when the method is left. In your `ReadBar` method, you can be sure that the bar is read every time when the method is called.