# Need clarification about Thread.MemoryBarrier()

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-barriers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why we need Thread.MemoryBarrier()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556351/why-we-need-thread-memorybarrier)

From O'Reilly's C# in a Nutshell:

```
class Foo
{
    int _answer;
    bool _complete;
    void A()
    {
        _answer = 123;
        Thread.MemoryBarrier(); // Barrier 1
        _complete = true;
        Thread.MemoryBarrier(); // Barrier 2
    }
    void B()
    {
        Thread.MemoryBarrier(); // Barrier 3
        if (_complete)
        {
            Thread.MemoryBarrier(); // Barrier 4
            Console.WriteLine (_answer);
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose methods A and B ran concurrently on different threads:

---

The author says: "Barriers 1 and 4 prevent this example from writing “0”. Barriers 2 and 3 provide a
freshness guarantee: they ensure that if B ran after A, reading _complete would evaluate
to true."

My questions are:

1. Why Barrier 4 is needed ? Barrier 1 isn't enough ?
2. Why 2 & 3 are needed ?
3. From what I understand, the barrier prevent executing instructions prior to its location after its following instructions, am I correct ?

Comment: The main clarification that will benefit you: never write code that needs any of this. Use `lock`, `InterLocked` and other std classes.

Comment: It is more of a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493931/why-do-i-need-a-memorybarrier rather than the one linked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Memory barrier enforces ordering constraint on reads and writes from/to memory: memory access operations before the barrier happen-before the memory access after the barrier.

1. Barriers 1 and 4 have complementary roles: barrier 1 ensures that the **write** to `_answer` happens-before the write to `_complete`, while barrier 4 ensures that the **read** from `_complete` happens-before the read from `_answer`. Imagine barrier 4 isn't there, but barrier 1 is. While it is guaranteed that `123` is written to `_answer` before `true` is written to `_complete` some other thread running `B()` may still have its read operations reordered and hence it may read `_answer` before it reads `_complete`. Similarly if barrier 1 is removed with barrier 4 kept: while the read from `_complete` in `B()` will always happen-before the read from `_answer`, `_complete` could still be written to before `_answer` by some other thread running `A()`.
2. Barriers 2 and 3 provide freshness guarantee: if barrier 3 is executed after barrier 2 then the state visible to the thread running `A()` at the point when it executes barrier 2 becomes visible to the thread running `B()` at the point when it executes barrier 3. In the absence of any of these two barriers `B()` executing after `A()` completed might not see the changes made by `A()`. In particular barrier 2 prevents the value written to `_complete` from being cached by the processor running `A()` and forces the processor to write it out to the main memory. Similarly, barrier 3 prevents the processor running `B()` from relying on cache for the value of `_complete` forcing a read from the main memory. Note however that stale cache isn't the only thing which can prevent freshness guarantee in the absence of memory barriers 2 and 3. Reordering of operations on the memory bus is another example of such mechanism.
3. Memory barrier just ensures that the effects of **memory access** operations are ordered across the barrier. Other instructions (e.g. increment a value in a register) may still be reordered.

Comment: I think Barrier 2 is mostly required to ensure that true is actually written to _complete. If it was not there the compiler could cash the value in a processor register for a while. This is particularly important as functions A and B are so simple they are likely to be inlined into the calling method. Like wise Barrier 3 is required to ensure that _complete is read fresh from memory and a register cashed copy isn't used.

Comment: Thanks, but two things though: **first**, to make sure: barrier 4 is needed in case the CPU caches `_answer` even before the execution-path in `B` is known (since the `WriteLine` is inside an `if` branch) ? **Second**: I think you were confused - please correct me if not, to make sure that the confusion is not mine - with: "...While it is guaranteed that true is written to _complete before 123 is written to _answer...", I believe you meant the other way: "...While it is guaranteed that 123 is written to _answer before true is written to _complete...".

Comment: First: that's right. Second: indeed. I've corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here we go:
A memory barrier prevents an optimizing compiler from reordering instructions. This means that no instruction before the barrier can be executed after an instruction that follows the barrier. There are several types of barriers but I will not go into details. Also, a CPU with weak memory ordering can reorder instructions and can create deadlocks. So:

1. Barrier 4 is needed to make the thread running method B read the up-to-date value of _answer (i.e. reading 123 instead of 0). It can occur that, if you compile in Release mode, the compiler will optimize the code and reorder instructions such that it is possible for the thread running B to read 0, even though the instruction you wrote would logically make this impossible (since _answer is assigned before _complete).
2. Barriers 2 & 3 also prevent reordering (as well as caching of the value of _complete) such that there is no way that the thread running B will ever read _complete as false, provided it ran after A.
3. The answer is above.