# Not understanding the purpose of memory barriers in C#

Tags: c#, thread-safety

before I start I just want to acknowledge that I am aware there are questions about this before that I've linked below:

[Why do I need a memory barrier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493931/why-do-i-need-a-memory-barrier)

[Why we need Thread.MemoryBarrier()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556351/why-we-need-thread-memorybarrier)

That said... I've read both and still don't quite understand what's going on from the basic level.

```
class Foo
{
  int _answer;
  bool _complete;

  void A()
  {
    _answer = 123;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 1
    _complete = true;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 2
  }

  void B()
  {
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 3
    if (_complete)
    {
      Thread.MemoryBarrier();       // Barrier 4
      Console.WriteLine (_answer);
    }
  }
}
```

This code snippet is taken from C# 4.0 in a Nutshell. Currently, I understand the problem without memory barriers is that there's a possibility that B will run before A and B will print nothing because `_complete` could be evaluated as `false`.

The "barriers" in each function are completely separate with each other and it's not like the barriers are ordered... `Thread.MemoryBarrier(1)` or anything so the compiler doesn't know **A** should go before **B**.

**Could someone clear this up for me? Thanks**

**EDIT:** I think I'm confused about how instruction ordering works... but I'm so confused about the topic that I'm not even sure how to phrase my question appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently, I understand the problem without memory barriers is that
>   there's a possibility that B will run before A and B will print
>   nothing because _complete could be evaluated as false.

No, the problem is in compiler, jitter or CPU instruction reordering.
It can be case, when some of them could reorder

```
_answer = 123;
_complete = true;
```

instructions for some optimization as form point of view single threaded application there is no matter order of them.

Now suppose they are reordered as

```
_complete = true;
_answer = 123;
```

now:

- Thread 1 set `_complete = true`
- Thread 2 get `_complete`

  - evaluate `if` condition
  - get _answer (which is 0)
  - Console.WriteLine(_answer) ->0
- Thread 1 set `_answer = 123`

The code logic broken.

Comment: OMG! I completely get it now,  I can't believe it was that simple. I was completely over thinking it. I have 1 more follow up question if you don't mind.

Comment: Which part of code is Thread.MemoryBarrier(); controlling? For example.... the first call Thread.MemoryBarrier() ... What what piece of code is that "stopping" from being reorganized?

Comment: First memory barrier set full fence and disallows moving `_answer = 123;` next to the `_complete = true;` and vise versa and second barrier releases the cash line of CPU and ensures that the `_answer` and `_complete` are fresh.